# Data not being sent via JQuery/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

i am trying to send the contents of an input box to a php file via JQuery/AJAX. When the script runs, all seems well, however, I receive nothing back. The following is my ajax call;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#kinaseEntry").change(function ()    {

    var kinaseEntry = $("#kinaseEntry").val();
    var dataString = "kinaseEntry=" + kinaseEntry;

    $("#waiting").show(500);
    $("#message").hide(0);
    alert(kinaseEntry);

    //Fetch list from database
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "post.php",
        datatype: "json",
        data:   dataString,
        success : function(datas)   {
            $("#message").show(500);
            $("#message").html(datas);
            alert(datas);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

I get the following result in the address bar after the script has run;

> http://www.someaddress.com/test/?kinaseEntry=#

Any help will be greatly appreciated, I am only starting to familiarize with JSON.

This is the results form testing the php file

```
{"kinaseSKU":"ABL1","url":"https:\/\/products.beta.invitrogen.com\/ivgn\/en\/US\/adirect\/invitrogen?cmd=catProductDetail&showAddButton=true&productID=P3049","molecularWeight":"125.4 kDa","tracerSKU":"","antiSKU1":"","antiSKU2":"","bufferSKU":"","tracerConc":"","assayConc":""}
```

The input form looks like;

```
<form id="form" action="#">
<p>To begin, start typing a Kinase:</p>
<input type="text" size="25" name="kinaseEntry" id="kinaseEntry" />
</form>
```

Comment: what happens if you call post.php directly ? other thing: also add "complete" and "error" callback.

Comment: Are you by any chance posting the FORM by pressing ENTER?

Comment: Yes, the results are fetched after the enter button is hit

Comment: @JorgePinho have added an error callback, but still the same and no errors thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dataString = "kinaseEntry=" + kinaseEntry;
```

Since the problem is that you didn't receive feedback from the action url, you may want to check your post.php. Also if you are using datatype `json` make sure you do the following:

```
header("Content-type:application/json");
echo json_encode($variable); //where variable is your result
```

JQuery is strict on content type being received if you specify `json` as the datatype

Comment: adding the '=' sign didn't make any difference

Comment: please try checking your post.php

Comment: the php file already has what you mentioned when i test the php file by itself, i get the expected results in the right format

Comment: did you check that all code paths `echo` something? If there are paths without outputs, it will really fail on the client

Comment: since you are using `GET` try accessing the URL `post.php?kinaseEntry=thevalue` if something comes up, then it works but if nothing is printed then you have an error on your `post.php`

Comment: please remove `$("#message").hide(0);` I suspect that you cannot see the result since the element is hidden.. Kindly verify

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add the show message function, have updated

Comment: is it fixed now? or you are still having issues?

Comment: can you change the method to `post` instead of `GET`? also, please try removing the `return false`

Comment: do you get the first alert? what is the element type of `#kinaseEntry`?

Comment: the first alert displays what was typed in the text box

Comment: where can I see that form. I wanted to inspect the html and the javascript and perform some troubleshooting schemes.

Comment: I have updated with the form, I can add the php file if you'd like, but I believe it works fine

Comment: ok, i think i'm getting somewhere. I removed the 'name' attribute from the input field and firefox debug tells me the value was passed to the php script. However, the message div isn't populating with the data and the success alert is '[object Object]'

Comment: that's common to have an object. you should iterate on the result of the result to get the fields of the json object being returned. you may access them using `datas.kinaseSKU` format

Comment: i managed to get exactly what i was after! I did what you suggested and got a result in the right div. Thank you very much for taking the time to have a look at my problem

Comment: LOL a long thread for the comments though. keep on earning points so that you could join the chat :D

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form
>   `key1=value1&key2=value2`, or a map of the form `{key1: 'value1', key2:
>   'value2'}`. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a
>   query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent. This processing
>   can be circumvented by setting processData to false. The processing
>   might be undesirable if you wish to send an XML object to the server;
>   in this case, change the contentType option from
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded to a more appropriate MIME type.

You are just sending a plain string, not a key/value pair. Try adding an `=` to your string or use a map.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#kinaseEntry").change(function ()    {
        $("#waiting").show(500);
        $("#message").hide(0);

        //Fetch list from database
        $.getJSON("post.php", {
            kinaseEntry : $(this).val()
        }, function (datas) {
            $("#message").html(datas);
        })

        return false;
    });
});
```

Seems easier for me... =] Hope this helps.. =]